# Give, for example, several pairs belonging to the ratios

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

Give, for example, several pairs belonging to the relations:

1. min {x,y} > 0
2. max {|x|, |y|} ≤ 1
3. min {x,y} < 0
4. max {|x|, |y|} > 1

I absolutely do not understand what the task requires from me, please help!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.  First of all, none of these are "ratios".  Secondly, it is clear that they can not be met simultaneously.  If you want to find, say, real numbers satisfying each of them individually, that's easy enough.  $(x,y)=(75, 198.5)$ satisfies the first one and the last one, though not the other two.

Comment: ahh, im sorry English is not my native language and maybe I didn't mean it by the word "ratio"

Comment: By "ratio" I meant "relation"

Comment: Ok.  But the bigger question was:  are you just looking for pairs of real numbers which satisfy one of these?  As I say, you can do two at once, but you can't get more than two out of any pair.

Comment: Yes, im looking for pairs of real numbers, but what does mean "min" or "max" before pair of x and y, As I understood its minimal and maximal elements of set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing to understand. For 1. you need to give some examples of pairs $(x,y)$ for which $\min  \{ x,y \} >0$.

Here are some pairs: $$(1,2), (1,3), (24985, 0.0002)$$
these satisfy the relation $\min  \{ x,y \} >0$ because the minimum of the two values is a positive number (in other words the two numbers are both positive).

Here are some pairs that do not satisfy the relation $\min  \{ x,y \} >0$:
$$(-1, 3), (2, 0), (-4, -23)$$

Then the exercize asks to give some examples for the other three relation. It sholdn't be that hard.

EDIT: from the comments it seems that you don't know what $\min$ and $\max$ denote. These mean "minimum" and "maximum", which mean "the smallest element" and "the largest element". For example
$$\min \{ 2, 7, -15, 0 \} = -15$$
$$\min \{ 1,2,4 \} = 1$$
$$\max \{ 2, 7, -15, 0 \} = 7$$
$$\max \{ 1,2,4 \} = 4$$

Comment: thank you for the help